# ReactJS - Run useEffect only when third party library is fully loaded on the window object (Spotify SDK)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to initialize Spotify SDK on component mount and keep the instance inside my Redux state.
Therefore in my DashboardPage view I am running useEffect which dispatches connectPlayer action to initialize player.

The problem is it works but not always. It works every 1-2 refresh attempts. How can I ensure that this action will be only dispatched when window.Spotify object is available? I've tried using if statements and also adding this to the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      console.log("ready");
      dispatch(connectPlayer());
    };
  }, []);
```

Here is my action creator:

```
const playerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "player",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    connectPlayer: state => {
      const playerInst = new window.Spotify.Player({
        name: "Default Player",
        getOAuthToken: cb => cb(localStorage.getItem("access_token")),
        volume: 0.2
      });

      playerInst.addListener("ready", ({ device_id }) => {
        console.log("Ready with Device ID", device_id);
      });

      playerInst.addListener("player_state_changed", state => {
        console.log("player_state_changed", state);
      });

      playerInst.connect();

      state.playerInstance = playerInst;
    }
  }
});
```

I am loading Spotify SDK in public/index.html like that

```
<script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add the sdk at the very top of your web page before the react libraries. Browser will load the sdk first before loading any other lib.

Comment: What is the symptom when it _doesn't_ work?  `console.log("ready");` never executes or....?

Comment: @Sohail Unfortunately this does not help. @Henry_Mueller Every 1-2 attemps my connectPlayer() action gets dispatched. This is because sometimes it loads the window.Spotify on time, but then on the second attempt it says ```Uncaught Error: onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady is not defined``` So I assume that it all depends on whether SDK manage to load before action gets dispatched.

Comment: I've used setTimeout for dispatch function set to 100ms which fixes issue for my browser. However, I really feel like it is quite dirty fix and need better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onload = () => {
      window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
        console.log("ready");
        dispatch(connectPlayer());
       };
    }
  }, [])
```